# Rewrite Recursive Function in Typescript Cannot Find Name

Tags: typescript

I have the following recursive function written in JavaScript:

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
  let out = [];
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.Parent == parent) {
        let children = getNestedChildren(arr, item.ID);

        if (children.length) {
            item.children = children;
        }
        out.push(item);
    }
  });
  return out
}   //  getNestedChildren
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fp1zvf0h/7/

Refactoring to TypeScript in VS Code like:

```
private getNestedChildren(arr:object[], parent:number):object[] {
  let out:object[];
  arr.forEach((item:{ID:number, Parent:number, children:{}}) => {
    if (item.Parent === parent) {
      let children:object[] = getNestedChildren(arr, item.ID);

      if (children.length) {
        item.children = children;
      }
      out.push(item);
    }
  });
  return out;
} //  getNestedChildren
```

I get the compile error `Cannot find name 'getNestedChildren'` on the line:

```
let children:object[] = getNestedChildren(arr, item.ID);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that inside a class?

Comment: You are missing `this`. If you moved this function to be a class member you need `this.getNestedChildren...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the inclusion of the word `private`, it looks like this is an object method, in which case you should be calling `this.getNestedChildren(arr, item.ID);`

Comment: oh yeah. Easy one xD